# Identifying the calling code path for an API method

Tags: java, spring

I am interested in finding a pattern or strategy for identifying which code path called a specific API method (or set of methods).

Here are some examples of differentiation in my application:

1. Caller calls API via an exposed REST controller
2. Caller calls API via some other internal API
3. Caller calls API via a user-created plugin

The application does use Spring for core wiring as well as Spring Security.  However, the caller could be any user so using the Spring security context to inspect authentication or their associated granted authorities doesn't appear to be the right fit.  The same user could call into the API method via one of the exposed REST URIs or call in via an arbitrary plugin entry-way.

How can one manage this type of identification without exposing additional or semi-duplicated APIs for different entry-points?   I would like to be able to identify where a particular call originates.   Slight differences in functionality can occur depending on whether the call came from one of our REST endpoints as opposed to one user-generated plugin as opposed to some other user-generated plugin.

This could hint at using some form of interception/aspect, but I do not have control over plugin code since I did not generate it.  Plugins do have to register in order to get integrated so there is a programmatic hook there.

Looking for suggestions on how to manage this type of issue whether it's using additional Spring feature functionality or an alternative idea or library.

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is a nice question.

As far as i see there are these options:

- semi duplicated API (already mentioned above)
- different users (or user-groups)
- get callstack using reflection (but hard to do and not really recommended)
- instead of user you can use some kind of authorization-token "per session" and see if the session is create via HTTP call or if it is an "internal" session
- check some kind of session-id and save inside your session where it was created (internal or external, ...)

For now i don't see any other possibilities.

ps: to "flag" the session as internal/external can be done by adding an own spring handler.

Hope this brings you to the right point and helps you out.